# PHP return partial script

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am creating a php (let's call it pageX.php) file that produces some html. The html has a button that when you press it, I would like to send an AJAX request.

To avoid having multiple files, I want to send the AJAX request to the same file. (pageX.php)

I don't want the AJAX response to return the entire php generated response that it would have with a normal GET request to pageX.php. So I am looking for a php method to simply stop executing and return what it currently has.

I understand I can do this with a big if statement, but I don't like wrapping the bottom part of my code with all the braces. So I am almost looking for the equivelent of a "break" statement for php that will simply return the current php generated html.

Is that possible?

Comment: not (easily) possible. your "stop running" ajax request will be some OTHER http request, and be completely independent of the request that triggered your script.

Comment: You could use "exit".  But I don't know that that will totally suit your need.

Comment: AJAX is GET or POST?

Comment: if is ajax, include partial.php, else, include full.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send your ajax request to `pageX.php?ajax=y` now you can do this

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['ajax'])) {
//return ajax data
exit;
}
?>
//your Normal html code here
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I am looking for. Thank you for your time!